# Can't find a method to write property 'id' of type 'java.lang.Integer' in a bean of type ''package.myBean"

Tags: jsp, javabeans, jsp-tags

I am inserting the form elements into database tables using jsp and java beans. However , everytime I try to set integer property of java bean using  tag, it gives me the above error. Meanwhile it is working for string properties of the bean.

```xml
<jsp:setProperty name="newEmp" property="deptId" value='<%= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("deptId")) %>' />
```

If I use

```xml
<jsp:setProperty name="newEmp" property="*" />
```

deptId value is set to 0 everytime

Comment: can you please share your code?

Comment: please enclose other code snippets (e.g the bean), really anything that can shed some light on the problem.

Comment: bean has members String name, String address , String gender and Integer deptId . I can set values  to name, address and gender using jsp:setProperties , but it is not working for deptId

Answer (score 0):

setProperty can only take String values

try this

```
<jsp:setProperty name="newEmp" property="deptId" value="deptId" />
```

in your bean you can have setter getter which take deptID as string.. Parse them when you are going to insert in database

Answer (score 0):

Check your bean class whether the setter method was omitted,
integer variable is ok in my example code below:

```
public int getDeptId() {
        return deptId;
    }


public class Produce {
    private String name="电吉他";
    private double price=1880.5;
    private int count=100;
    private String factoryAdd="吉林省长春市";

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getFactoryAdd() {
        return factoryAdd;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}


<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<jsp:useBean id="produce" class="net.cs30.Produce"></jsp:useBean>
<jsp:setProperty name="produce" property="name" value="洗衣机"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="produce" property="count" value="12306"/>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>商品名称：<jsp:getProperty name="produce" property="name"></jsp:getProperty></li>
        <li>厂址：<jsp:getProperty name="produce" property="count"/></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/df7zP.png) from my output.

Answer (score 0):

```
<jsp:setProperty name="newEmp" property="deptId" value="deptId" />
```

Check whether parameter passing inside setter method of bean should be in datatype ***int*** . If it is in ***Integer*** it will not work.